# Matrix determinant computation

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

**Input :** An matrix $A$, whose entries are from $\mathbb{Z}$ (set of integers)

**Output:** det A (determinant of matrix A)

Question : Suppose we are solving this problem over $\mathbb{Q}$ using gaussian elimination, what could be the size of numerators and denominators of the intermediate results?

**Gaussian elimination:** By doing row elementary operations we will getting upper triangular matrix $U$, so $A = P_1\times P_2 \times P_2 ..P_k U$, where each $P_i$ is a permuatation matrix.

Please note that there efficient methods for the computation of determinant like modular determinant computation etc, but I want to compute with the method described above.

Comment: I have no proof, but if you are doing simple Gaussian elimination. You could run into exponential growth. If you're using an adapted elimination method similar to Kannan-Bachem's algorithm for Euclidean Rings, you should get coefficients in $O(\textrm{det}(A))$.

Comment: Does this [note of Lovász](http://www.cs.bu.edu/faculty/gacs/courses/cs530/lectures/exact-Gauss.pdf) help? (Taken from [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3921/what-is-the-actual-time-complexity-of-gaussian-elimination).)